# Using Biopython to run a BLAT search through NCBI

Tags: python, biopython, blast, ncbi

I'd like to run several BLAT queries with different sequences and then perform a multiple sequence alignment on the results.

How can I use Python to run these BLAT queries?

I know that there is a way to use BLAST, but I am not sure about BLAT.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to use BLAT online, there's not such tool as `Bio.Blast.NCBIWWW`.
- If you want to use BLAT locally, there's not such tool as `Bio.Blast.NCBIStandalone`

The good news are that you can install BLAT locally and use the `subprocess` library to call BLAT, and Biopython provides the `Bio.SearchIO.BlatIO` to parse the output. Or you can try to submit your queries to the website of BLAT, and get the output to parse it locally.

But if you're new to python, I think the first option is the easy path.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I've downloaded the blat files, now I just have to get python to recognize them as a sub library that I can call.

Comment: @ct4 I'm not sure what you mean. Python doesn't recognize anything from BLAT, except it can parse a result file. If you installed BLAT and can run it in a console, you can launch the same command from python.

Comment: Ah, I see. I can't run BLAT from the console on my lab Mac for some reason. I have the files downloaded, but any commands involving BLAT are not recognized.